# Rails 3 TestUnit file fixture Tempfile becomes String in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, minitest, testunit

I have the following code to test file uploading:

```
test 'when a user adds an attachment to an existing candidate, the attachment shows up on the candidates page' do
  user = login_user
  opportunity = opportunities(:with_candidates)
  candidate = candidates(:first)
  upload = fixture_file_upload(ActionController::TestCase.fixture_path + 'files/file_upload_support_image.jpeg', 'image/jpeg')
  attributes = { attachments: [upload]  }

  user.put opportunity_candidate_path(opportunity, candidate, request: attributes)
  user.follow_redirect!

  assert_match /#{upload.original_filename}/, fixer.response.body, 'The filename of the attachment should appear on the opportunity candidates page'
end
```

The test fails because the file does not get attached.

The code works when run through the browser – it turns out I had written the `assert` incorrectly and was getting a false pass. Now the `assert` is correct, the test fails.

When debugging, I find that the `upload` variable in the test is something like `#<Rack::Test::UploadedFile:0x007f85ca141c50>`. However, when I debug the controller, the value in the `params` hash is `"#<Rack::Test::UploadedFile:0x007f85ca141c50>"`.

Note the quote marks. Rails has turned the file upload into a string!

Since there’s none of my code between the test and the controller, and this works when the app is run in the browser, I guess something may be wrong with how I am constructing the params hash or the tempfile itself in the test.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, turns out I was doing something incorrectly in the test. However, this error does not manifest if you are passing the most common types of parameter, so it can be a little tricky to spot!

The line

```
user.put opportunity_candidate_path(opportunity, candidate, request: attributes)
```

Should be

```
user.put opportunity_candidate_path(opportunity, candidate), request: attributes
```

Note the moved parenthesis. D’oh!

The reason this may not be easy to spot is that unknown keys in the `..._path` method are *still passed as parameters*. However, they are parsed having been encoded into the URL querystring, like a `GET` request.

For the common cases of passing text values and integer foreign keys in as params, this mangling doesn’t prevent anything working, it’s only for more complex objects that it becomes an issue.